# 'get' keyword in typescript

Tags: typescript

```
private mouseHover:MouseEventHandler<HTMLElement> = new MouseEventHandler<HTMLElement>();
public get onMouseHover():  MouseEventHandler<HTMLElement> { return this.mouseHover; }
```

For the above code, I don't understand the 'get' keyword. Could anyone teach me the relative knowledge and give me examples? Thanks!

Comment: it creates a read only accessor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Could anyone teach me the relative knowledge and give me examples?

It allows you define a `getter` : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get

Basically the *function* `onMouseOver` gets *called* when someone *accesses* the property e.g. `console.log(onMouseOver)`

Answer (score 1):

In essence it allows you to control what happens when the property is *gotten*

In the example code you are tying to understand you have a private property `mouseHover`. This cannot be accessed outside the class it is defined. The author wanted a to make the `mouseHover` property accessible outside the class -- without allowing it to be overwritten -- in essence Read Only.

So the author exposed the private `mouseHover` property using the 'get' keyword on a new property `onMouseHover`. Using `get` the author can tell JavaScript what to do when the property is read. As you can see it just returns the backing property.

This gets compiled into the following JavaScript

```
Object.defineProperty(YourClass.prototype, "onMouseHover", {
    get: function () {
        return this.mouseHover;
    },
    enumerable: true,
    configurable: true
});
```

To understand this better, look at the documentation for Object.defineProperty
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty

Answer (score -1):

```
class SomeObject {

    public getFoo () {
        return 'foo';
    }

    public get foo () {
        return 'foo';
    }
}

var obj = new SomeObject();

// True
obj.getFoo() === obj.foo;

// Does nothing
obj.foo = 'bar';

// Still true
obj.getFoo() === obj.foo;

// Does nothing
delete obj.foo;

// Still true
obj.getFoo() === obj.foo;

// Does nothing
SomeObject.prototype.foo = 'bar';

// Still true
obj.getFoo() === obj.foo;

// It's gone from all instances of SomeObject
delete SomeObject.prototype.foo;

// True
typeof obj.foo === 'undefined';
```